# I cannoot get my scroll bar to behave properly in react using javascript, can anyone see an issue?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to make a react site (first time so forgive me if I have made dumb mistakes and am missing something obvious).
My nav bar is currently fixed at the top of my page it has some basic animations on-hover.
I want it to disappear when scrolling down and reappear when scrolling up.
Like in this youtube video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RYUuGgC_IY0

Here is my current Javascript

```
import React from 'react';
import './Header.css';

const body = document.body;
let lastScroll = 0;

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  const currentScroll = window.pageYOffset;
  if (currentScroll <= 0) {
    body.classList.remove("scroll-up");
  }
  if (currentScroll > lastScroll && !body.classList.contains("scroll-down")) {
    body.classList.remove("scroll-up");
    body.classList.add("scroll-down");
  }
  if (currentScroll < lastScroll && body.classList.contains("scroll-down")) {
    body.classList.remove("scroll-down");
    body.classList.add("scroll-up");
  }
  lastScroll = currentScroll;
});
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header className="header">
      <div className="logo-container">
        <a href="https://github.com/avarga1"><i className="fab fa-github"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/austin-varga-2611b9259/"><i className="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
        <a href="#home"><i className="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/"><i className="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
      </div>
       <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#home" className="nav-link">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#home" className="nav-link">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#home" className="nav-link">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#home" className="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

and here is my css

```
.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: rgb(85, 85, 85);
  opacity: 0.85;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
 width: 100%;
}

.header .logo-container {
  display: flex;
 }

.header .logo-container a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;  
}

.header .logo-container a i {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 10px;  
}

.header .logo-container a i:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.header .username {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.header nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

.header nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.header nav ul li a.nav-link {
  padding-right: 40px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header nav ul li a.nav-link:hover {
  color: rgb(30, 255, 10);
  font-weight: bold;
  transform: scale(1.5) !important;
}

.header .logo-container a i.fab.fa-linkedin:hover {
  color: rgb(0, 123, 181);
}
.header .logo-container a i.fab.fa-twitter:hover {
  color: rgb(29, 161, 242);
}

.header .logo-container a i.fab.fa-github:hover {
  color: black;
}

.header .logo-container a i.fab.fa-youtube:hover {
  color: rgb(203, 32, 39);
}

/*   Scroll      */
.scroll-down header {
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
}

.scroll-up header {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Here is my react App.js file as well

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header.js';
import Contact from './Contact.js';
import Landing from './Landing.js';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar.js';
import Main from './Main.jsx';


function App() {
  return (
    <div>  
        <Header/>
        <Main />
        <Sidebar />
        <Landing />
        <Contact />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I cannot seem to get it to behave as intended, any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why bother using React here? It doesn't appear to be doing much of anything. In a normal React app, it manages the event listeners.

Comment: It's a project in the Meta frontend developer course.
There are a bunch of other files but I managed to get them to work properly, the navbar is all that's not working. As far as why bother using react for this, I don't have an answer for that, is it not beneficial to use when writing jsx and just dealing with larger amounts of code in general?

Comment: In the code you showed before the update, it served no purpose. Still, if you're using React, I'd use it to manage all event listeners, so I'd move that listener out of the global scope into a component, or use an IntersectionObserver.

Answer (score 0):

The code execution should be broken out of, from one if-condition block, if the purpose for that check is done.

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  const currentScroll = window.pageYOffset;

  if (currentScroll <= 0) {
    body.classList.remove("scroll-up");
    return; // or return with a value or setup the lastScroll = currentScroll before this empty return;
  }
   
  if (currentScroll > lastScroll && !body.classList.contains("scroll-down")) {
    body.classList.remove("scroll-up");
    body.classList.add("scroll-down");
    return; // or return with a value or setup the lastScroll = currentScroll before this empty return;
  }

  if (currentScroll < lastScroll && body.classList.contains("scroll-down")) {
    body.classList.remove("scroll-down");
    body.classList.add("scroll-up");
    return; // or return with a value or setup the lastScroll = currentScroll before this empty return;
  }


  
  lastScroll = currentScroll;
  
});
```

One other key point to note is where does the `scroll-up` and `scroll-down` function gets attached to. The position of Header component in DOM tree inside the body would matter. The code checks in `body.classList.contains("scroll-down")`, where as it should be known if the class-name is attached/attributed to the parent-div of the Header component?

Comment: I added the 'return' as you stated above but that alone did not fix it,
I attached my App.js in the question as well if thats what you are referring to?
I'm not sure if that answers the question...

Comment: @oz.vegas so the class-list looks at the classes attached to the body. `body.classList.remove("scroll-up");` which is above in the DOM tree where the App.js renders the app. You might want to access the particular Header component and then attach/remove it. `return` statement would make sure the function doesn't run additional logic going forward, so that's why it was suggested.